# How to input list of integer separated by newline in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, newline

I want to insert a list of integer separted by newline like this

```
input = arr = 4\n6\n-2\n3\n-1\n

so that I can get the list like this: 

output = [4,6,-2,3,-1]
```

But I don't know how to do it.
I used split('\n') and splitlines() but it give output like this:

```
input = 4\n6\n-2\n3\n-1

output = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python code\tcs_mock_code.py", line 15, in <module>
    r = list(map(int, arr.splitlines()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4\\n6\\n-2\\n3\\n-1'
```

here is the code:

```
arr = input() 
print(arr)

r = list(map(int, arr.splitlines()))

print(r)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
arr=input()

r=list(map(int,arr.split("\\n")))
print(r)
```

input :

```
4\n6\n-2\n3\n-1
```

output :

```
[4, 6, -2, 3, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
str_input = "4\n6\n-2\n3\n-1\n"
list(map(int, str_input.splitlines()))
# [4, 6, -2, 3, -1]
```

Don't override builtins, it's bad pratice:

```
input = arr
```

You're overriding `input` (builtin) by assigning it a value.

Comment: The text should be taken from input

Comment: I guess you're right. The question could be clearer.